# Does cum laude in DEFENSE (not in THESIS) mean no academic career in Germany?

Tags: phd, germany, grades, defense

My PhD is in social studies. I received magna cum laude for the thesis and cum laude for the defense. The lower grade in the defense was the result of my nervousness and a personal issue with one of the cross examiners, but I'm not going into that now.

How devastating is the low defense grade for my future career in academia? The overall grade is still magna cum laude, but the PhD certificate also contains the cum laude grade for the defense, and we know that in Germany cum laude is the second lowest grade.

I've published in many peer-reviewed journals, and my thesis has also been published as a book by a highly prestigious international publisher. Will this salvage the cum laude grade for the defense?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess I'm puzzled. If "with honors" is considered a negative then it would seem that "honors" are essentially meaningless and applied without thought to everything. True?

Comment: @Buffy I agree. It's just like that in Germany. The best to worst grading is SCL, MCL, CL, and rite (passable).

Comment: My advice is that you stress the positives in any hiring situation and just ignore this. Especially if you can't change it.

Comment: And, I assume "failed" is also an option for the defense. I've sent one or two candidates back to work in the defense, but in this case they had a chance to improve the work and come back. Maybe not the same in Germany.

Comment: @Evangeline I don't think your other closed question is actually a duplicate. So: For the formal requirements of a professor position, a worse-than-average separate defense grade is not a problem because for the formal part, the overall grade counts. But you never know if somebody in the hiring committee finds this not so great and proposes removing your application from the stack of candidates to consider, which however applies to every aspect of every candidate in a hiring committee hearing.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question because it's a different question than the alleged duplicate.

Comment: @DCTLib Do you think the cards are stacked against me and I should better look for an academic post outside Germany? Based on your experience, would they not take my numerous peer-reviewed publications into account? I even finished my PhD in less than 3 years (2,5 years) while my colleagues needed 5 to 6 years in general. Sad that a hiccup at the end could ruin it all (tbh, I already had a bad feeling about the defense grade when they announced that the cross examiner was the one I had had an issue with in the past...).

Comment: @Evangeline Every university has a bit of its own dynamics in these hiring committees, so I can't really speak universally. Personally I would ignore this extra grade after the interview, because whether the person in question does a good job presenting concepts orally will become obvious in this interview and the application talk - and then there is no need to look at the performance from >3 years ago (earlier, the "Habilitationsäquivalenz" will often be questionable). But that's just me. Whether you get asked to participate in an interview is quite unlikely to depend on this grade.